# How to map a complex structure in jsp view to a model object in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm using spring mvc for the first time and I'm trying to display and edit a structure in jsp.

I have a class Snippet, which holds a list of objects of type Sentence:

```
public class Snippet {
  private int id;
  private List<Sentence> sentences;
  // getters, setters, default constructor
}

public class Sentence {
  private int id;
  private int scale;
  private String text;
  // getters, setters, default constructor
}
```

In my controller I give a new snippet for editing and when user clicks "save" store it to my db, then return another one. Currently the sentences list of the snippet is null:

```
@RequestMapping("/snippet")
public ModelAndView getSnippet() {
  return new ModelAndView("snippet", "snippet", snippetService.getSnippet());
}

@RequestMapping("/save")
public ModelAndView saveSnippet(@ModelAttribute Snippet snippet) {
  if(snippet != null && snippet.getSentences() != null && !snippet.getSentences().isEmpty()) {
    snippetService.updateSnippet(snippet);
  }
  return new ModelAndView("snippet", "snippet", snippetService.getSnippet());
}
```

In my snippet.jsp I'd like to display the snippet sentences with their scale, and on save, pass snippet with sentences and scales to the controller for storage:

```
<form:form method="post" action="save" modelAttribute="snippet">
  ...
  <c:forEach var="sentence" items="${snippet.sentences}">
    <tr>
      <td>${sentence.id}</td>
      <td>${sentence.text}</td>
      <td><input type="range" name="sentence.scale" value="${sentence.scale}"
         path="sentence.scale" min="0" max="5" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
  </tr>
```

I think I have to find the right way to use the path attribute but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSTL `c:forEach` tag provides the attribute `varStatus`, which will expose the loop status to the specified variable.  Reference the `index` of `varStatus` to obtain the index of the current loop and use that index to specify the index of the collection item you want to bind or display.

```
<c:forEach var="sentence" items="${snippet.sentences}" varStatus="i">
    <tr>
      <td>${sentence.id}</td>
      <td>${sentence.text}</td>
      <td>
        <form:input type="range" 
          name="snippet.sentences[${i.index}].scale" 
          path="sentences[${i.index}].scale" 
          min="0" max="5" 
          /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```